# mail sending failed from localhost in laravel 8

Tags: laravel

Env configuration:

```
    MAIL_MAILER=smtp
    MAIL_HOST=smtpgmail.com
    MAIL_PORT=587
    MAIL_USERNAME=laravellocal***@gmail.com
    MAIL_PASSWORD=*******
    MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
    MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=laravellocalhost@gmail.com
    MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

I used this function to send link on mail

```php
public function forgotPassword(Request $request) {
    $request->validate([
        'email'=> 'required|email',
    ]);

    $email = $request->email;
    $user = User::where('email', $email)->first();

    if (! $user) {
        return response([
            'message' => 'Email not exist',
            'status' => 'failed'
        ], 404);
    }

    $token = Str::random(40);

    PasswordReset::updateOrCreate([
        'email' => $email,
        'token' => $token,
        'created_at' => Carbon::now()
    ]);

    // dump('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/reset' . $token);

    Mail::send('forgotPassword', ['token' => $token], function( Message $message) use ($email) {
        $message->subject('Reset You password');
        $message->to($email);
    });
        
    return response([
        'message' => 'Password Reset link sent.. Check your Email',
        'status' => 'Success'
    ], 200);
}
```

But I got this error in postman:

> Connection could not be established with host localhost :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://localhost:587 (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.)

Comment: `smtpgmail.com`? That should be `smtp.gmail.com` I think

Comment: `smtpgmail.com` should indeed be `smtp.gmail.com` as @brombeer mentioned. As a port you should use `465` instead and mail_encryption should be `ssl`. Furthermore please ensure your gmail account has 2-step verification enabled and you've created an app password and use it as `MAIL_PASSWORD`. More info [here](https://medium.com/@laraveltuts/how-to-send-mail-using-gmail-in-laravel-9-76d110779a4a)